# javascript regex globally case insensitive issue

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

I can't seem to find the solution for a regex issue I am facing:

I have an array of ticket numbers(strings) I want to filter them with regex then obviously remove the the regex string from the numbers so I end up with the numbers only.
At the moment it seems that the regex str is mainly a prefix but I don't want to limit my code for something like this: /(^ex)/i
It worked but if somewhy this rule breaks and it becomes a suffix maybe then my regex isn't valid then..

I want to check globally and case insensitively if the string has ex in anyway in the string(prefix, suffix, ex, EX, eX, Ex)...

```
const TicketNumbers = ['ex12', 'EX34', 'eX21', 'Ex77', '85ex', '767EX', '523eX', '236Ex']

const exPrefix = /ex/gi;

const exTickets = TicketNumbers
  .filter(ticket => exPrefix.test(ticket))
  .map(ticket => ticket.replace(exPrefix, ''));
```

Problem:

- /ex/gi : this is ok for ex, EX for prefix and suffix but doesn't solve eX or Ex..
- /(^ex)/i : this remove ex in all version but it is only a prefix

Comment: Looks like all you need is `const exTickets = TicketNumbers.filter(ticket => /ex/i.test(ticket)).map(ticket => ticket.replace(/ex/gi, ''));`

Comment: but how could I keep the regex in a variable I don't want to pollute my code? as soon as it works I want to move it maybe into a helper or a constant file outside. @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: You cannot use `g` flag with a regex used in `RegExp#test`, so you need two regexps.

Comment: I think your problem is with using regex.test as I recall this changes a start index variable in the regex object and can make subsequent regex queries fail

Comment: https://benjaminjohnson.me/regex-test-side-effects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `String.search` or `String.match` instead of `test`:

```js
const TicketNumbers = ['ex1', '2eX', '3Ex4', '5EX6', 'foo']

const exPrefix = /ex/ig;

const exTickets = TicketNumbers
    .filter(ticket => ticket.search(exPrefix) >= 0)
    .map(t => t.replace(exPrefix, ''))

console.log(exTickets)
```

`test` and friends are broken and it's better to stay away from them

Comment: This is no longer case insensitive.

Comment: @gog It seems to work for me, 2 question though:
why >= 0 needed and why replaceAll instead of replace?
it work as you wrote I just want to know why you wrote the way you did, what it does in the background? Thanks

Comment: `>=0` is needed because `search` returns an zero-based index or -1 if a regex did not match. You could use `match` without a comparison instead: `.filter(x => x.match(regex))`.

Comment: `replaceAll` was a mistake, corrected now